# How to Save Data From Firebase to SQLite Android

Tags: firebase, sqlite, firebase-realtime-database, android-sqlite

I am fetching some data from Firebase and Trying to Save the data to SQLite Database in the same `onDataChange method` Below is the code I have tried so far. I am saving fetched data in String variable.when I try with `Toast` it shows fetched value and also when i use hard coded value for the variable like `String drivername="some value"` it is saving data to sqlite but when I am trying to save the fetched value it is returning null value hence not saving.What's wrong I am doing

```
    String mobile_no=localSharedPreferences.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PhoneNumber);

    DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Driver");

    reference.orderByKey().equalTo(mobile_no).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String drivermobile=localSharedPreferences.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PhoneNumber);

            for(DataSnapshot datas: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    String drivername = datas.child("d_nme").getValue(String.class);
                    String avatorurl = datas.child("d_avtr").getValue(String.class);
                    String vehicleno = datas.child("v_No").getValue(String.class);
                    String vehiclename = datas.child("v_nme").getValue(String.class);

                   //Toast is showing fetched drivername correctly 
                   Toast.makeText(SigninActivity.this, drivername, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                //Trying to save into SQLITE

                ContactsDB db = new ContactsDB(getApplicationContext());
                db.open();
                db.createEntry(drivermobile, drivername, vehiclename, avatorurl, vehicleno);
                db.close();


                Toast.makeText(SigninActivity.this, localSharedPreferences.getSharedPreferences(Constants.dDrivername), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
```

And this is my  ContactsDB Class

```
public class ContactsDB {

public static final String KEY_ROWID="_id";
public static final String DRIVER_MOBILE="driver_mobile";
public static final String DRIVER_NAME="driver_firstname";
public static final String VEHICLE_NAME="vehicle_name";
public static final String AVATOR_URL="driver_avator";
public static final String VEHICLE_NO="vehicle_no";

private final String DATABASE_NAME="ContactsDB";
private final String DATABASE_TABLE="ContactsTable";
private final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

private DBHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabse;

public  ContactsDB(Context context)
{
    ourContext=context;
}

private class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    public DBHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        /**
         * THIS Only runs if database not exists with specified version
         */

        String sqlcode="CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                DRIVER_MOBILE + " INTEGER NOT NULL, " +
                DRIVER_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                VEHICLE_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                AVATOR_URL + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                VEHICLE_NO + " DECIMAL NOT NULL);";

        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sqlcode);

    }
}


public ContactsDB open() throws SQLException
{
    ourHelper=new DBHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabse=ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;
}

public void close()
{
    ourHelper.close();
}

public long createEntry(String drivermobile, String drivername, String vehiclename, String avatorurl, String vehicleno) {


    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(DRIVER_MOBILE, drivermobile);
    cv.put(DRIVER_NAME,drivername);
    cv.put(VEHICLE_NAME,vehiclename);
    cv.put(AVATOR_URL,avatorurl);
    cv.put(VEHICLE_NO,vehicleno);
    return ourDatabse.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);

}

public  String getData()
{
    /*Here you can Specify which column value you want to retrieve*/

    String [] columns=new String[] {KEY_ROWID,DRIVER_MOBILE,DRIVER_NAME,VEHICLE_NAME,AVATOR_URL,VEHICLE_NO};
    Cursor c=ourDatabse.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null,null,null,null,null);

    String result="";

    int iKeyID=c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iRowID=c.getColumnIndex(DRIVER_MOBILE);
    int iFirstName=c.getColumnIndex(DRIVER_NAME);
    int iSecondName=c.getColumnIndex(VEHICLE_NAME);
    int iAvatorUrl=c.getColumnIndex(AVATOR_URL);
    int iRatings=c.getColumnIndex(VEHICLE_NO);

    for(c.moveToFirst();!c.isAfterLast();c.moveToNext())
    {

        result=result + c.getString(iKeyID) + ": " + c.getString(iRowID) + ": " + c.getString(iFirstName) + ": " +
                c.getString(iSecondName) + ": " + c.getString(iAvatorUrl) + "+ " +
                c.getString(iRatings) + "\n"; // n is for newline
    }
    c.close();
    return result;

}


public  long deleteEntry(String rowId)
{
    return ourDatabse.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=?", new String[]{rowId});
}


public  long updateEntry(String rowId, String drivermobile, String drivername, String vehiclename, String avatorurl, String vehicleno)
{
   ContentValues cv=new ContentValues();

   /*if you update one column then put only one column or put as many as many you want to update*/
   cv.put(DRIVER_MOBILE, drivermobile);
   cv.put(DRIVER_NAME,drivername);
   cv.put(VEHICLE_NAME,vehiclename);
   cv.put(AVATOR_URL,avatorurl);
   cv.put(VEHICLE_NO,vehicleno);
   return ourDatabse.update(DATABASE_TABLE, cv, KEY_ROWID + "=?", new String[]{rowId});
}
```

Comment: Post the code of the ContactsDB class.

Comment: Edited my question with contactsdb code

Comment: `createEntry()` is a method that returns an integer value. Did you check it? If it is <0 then insert failed. Also don't open and close the database inside the loop. Do this: ` ContactsDB db = new ContactsDB(getApplicationContext());` before the loop and this: `db.close();` after the loop.

Comment: this exactly solved my problem thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you try the following :-

## 1.

Add the following getter method to ContactsDB.java :-

```
public SQLiteDatabase getOurDatabse() {
    return ourDatabse;
}
```

## 2

Move the **open** and **close** to before and after the loop respectively and also include a **beginTransaction** before the loop and after the loop a **setTransactionSuccessful** and an **endTransaction**.

As such the disk will be written to just the once rather than for each insert.

e.g. :-

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

    ContactsDB db = new ContactsDB(getApplicationContext());
    db.open();
    db.getOurDatabse().beginTransaction();


    String drivermobile = localSharedPreferences.getSharedPreferences(Constants.PhoneNumber);

    for (DataSnapshot datas : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


        String drivername = datas.child("d_nme").getValue(String.class);
        String avatorurl = datas.child("d_avtr").getValue(String.class);
        String vehicleno = datas.child("v_No").getValue(String.class);
        String vehiclename = datas.child("v_nme").getValue(String.class);

        //Toast is showing fetched drivername correctly
        Toast.makeText(SigninActivity.this, drivername, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        //Trying to save into SQLITE

        if (drivermobile != null && drivername != null && vehiclename != null && avatorurl != null && vehicleno != null) {
            if (db.createEntry(drivermobile, drivername, vehiclename, avatorurl, vehicleno) > 0) {
                Toast.makeText(SigninActivity.this, localSharedPreferences.getSharedPreferences(Constants.dDrivername), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SigninActivity.this, "?????? Not ADDED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(SigninActivity.this, "?????? Unable to ADD due to NULL value(s)", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    db.getOurDatabse().setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.getOurDatabse().endTransaction();
    db.close();
```

- This additionally does some checking so that null values will not result in an attempt to insert but will toast that it is unable to add the row.
- It also checks the return from each insert to see if the row was inserted and Toast's accordingly.

  - However, I would suggest that writing the messages to the Log rather than (or as well ass) Toast would aid debugging.